# In a django model custom save() method, how should you identify a new object?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to trigger a special action in the `save()` method of a Django `Model` object when I'm saving a new record (not updating an existing record.)

Is the check for (`self.id != None`) necessary and sufficient to guarantee the self record is new and not being updated?  Any special cases this might overlook?

Comment: Please select https://stackoverflow.com/a/35647389/8893667 as the correct answer. The answer doesn't work in many cases like a `UUIDField pk`

Answer (score 249, accepted):

**Updated:** With the clarification that `self._state` is not a private instance variable, but named that way to avoid conflicts, checking `self._state.adding` is now the preferable way to check.

---

```
self.pk is None:
```

returns True within a new Model object, unless the object has a `UUIDField` as its `primary_key`.

The corner case you might have to worry about is whether there are uniqueness constraints on fields other than the id (e.g., secondary unique indexes on other fields). In that case, you could still have a new record in hand, but be unable to save it.

Comment: The corner case of save failure can be dealt with by wrapping the super() call in a try-except block and doing any necessary cleanup for the "special action".

Comment: You should use `is not` rather than `!=` when checking for identity with the `None` object

Comment: Not all models have an id attribute, i.e. a model extending another through a `models.OneToOneField(OtherModel, primary_key=True)`.  I think you need to use `self.pk`

Comment: @AJP, you're right. You should always use `pk` rather than `id`, especially if you aren't certain whether `id` exists in your model or has been overridden. This happens if you have any field with `primary_key=True` or any field named `id` that isn't the PK.

Comment: This MAY NOT WORK in some cases. Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/940928/145349

Comment: This is not the correct answer. If using a `UUIDField` as a primary key, `self.pk` is never `None`.

Comment: Side note: This answer pre-dated UUIDField.

Comment: This is the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35647389/8893667

The given answer is unreliable at times and as mentioned above when you use `UUIDField`

Comment: This will also NOT work when you are saving a multi-table Child Model Class. The parent instance is created first before saving the child instance. And by default, the pk for the child instance is attained from the parent instance's pk.

Comment: The primary **readable way** I think should be:

```self._state.adding is True``` - ***creating*** /

```self._state.adding is False``` - ***updating***

Comment: self._state.adding is the true way to go, in any case will work.

Comment: >`"self._state is not a private instance variable, but named that way to avoid conflicts"` 

is there a source for this please? @DaveW.Smith

Answer (score 366):

Alternative way to checking `self.pk` we can check `self._state` of the model

`self._state.adding is True` creating

`self._state.adding is False` updating

I got it from this [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading)

Comment: This is the only correct way when using a custom primary key field.

Comment: Not sure about all the details of how `self._state.adding` works, but fair warning that it seems to always equal `False` if you're checking it _after_ calling `super(TheModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/db/models/base.py#L799

Comment: This is the correct way and should be upvoted/set as the correct answer.

Comment: You should always be careful when using private attributes or methods from Django though, so even if it works it might not be the best solution

Comment: @guival: `_state` isn’t private; like `_meta`, it’s prefixed with an underscore to avoid confusion with field names. (Notice how it’s used in the linked documentation.)

Comment: This is the best way. I used `is_new = self._state.adding`, then `super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` and then `if is_new: my_custom_logic()`

Comment: this is a great way to overide django admin's save models methods. thanks..

Comment: The real correct answer. Some times you can create an object setting an ID, so check for pk is None will not work.

Comment: I recently observed a case where someone took an existing model instance, set `pk` to `None` (django way of copying a model) and `self._state.adding` was `False` during `save`. So probably both `_adding` and `pk` should be checked to cover all possible cases.

Answer (score 53):

Checking `self.id` assumes that `id` is the primary key for the model. A more generic way would be to use the [pk shortcut](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut).

`is_new = self.pk is None`

Comment: Pro Tip: put this **BEFORE** the `super(...).save()`.

Answer (score 43):

The check for `self.pk == None` is **not** sufficient to determine if the object is going to be inserted or updated in the database.

The Django O/RM features an especially nasty hack which is basically to check if there is something at the PK position and if so do an UPDATE, otherwise do an INSERT (this gets optimised to an INSERT if the PK is None).

The reason why it has to do this is because you are allowed to set the PK when an object is created. Although not common where you have a sequence column for the primary key, this doesn't hold for other types of primary key field.

If you really want to know you have to do what the O/RM does and look in the database.

Of course you have a specific case in your code and for that it is quite likely that `self.pk == None` tells you all you need to know, but it is *not* a general solution.

Comment: Good point!  I can get away with this in my application (checking for None primary key) because I never set the pk for new objects.  But this would definitely not be a good check for a reusable plugin or part of the framework.

Comment: This is specially true when you assign the primary key yourself and and through the database. In that case the surest thing to do is to make a trip to the db.

Comment: Even if your application code does not specify pks explicitly the fixtures for your test cases might. Though, as they are commonly loaded before the tests it might not be a problem.

Comment: This is especially true in the case of using a `UUIDField` as a Primary Key: the key isn't populated at the DB level, so `self.pk` is always `True`.

Comment: This solution also works for this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35647389/4379151

Answer (score 12):

You could just connect to post_save signal which sends a "created" kwargs, if true, your object has been inserted.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: That can potentially cause race conditions if there's a lot of load.  That's because the post_save signal is sent on save, but before the transaction has been committed.  This can be problematic and can make things very difficult to debug.

Comment: I'm not sure if things changed (from older versions), but my signal handlers are called within the same transaction so a failure anywhere rolls back the whole transaction.  I'm using `ATOMIC_REQUESTS`, so I'm not really sure about the default.

Answer (score 7):

Check for `self.id` and the `force_insert` flag.

```
if not self.pk or kwargs.get('force_insert', False):
    self.created = True

# call save method.
super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

#Do all your post save actions in the if block.
if getattr(self, 'created', False):
    # So something
    # Do something else
```

This is handy because your newly created object(self) has it `pk` value

Answer (score 7):

I'm very late to this conversation, but I ran into a problem with the self.pk being populated when it has a default value associated with it.

The way I got around this is adding a date_created field to the model

`date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

From here you can go

`created = self.date_created is None`

Answer (score 6):

For a solution that also works even when you have a `UUIDField` as a primary key (which as others have noted isn't `None` if you just override `save`), you can plug into Django's [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save) signal. Add this to your *models.py*:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def mymodel_saved(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # do extra work on your instance, e.g.
        # instance.generate_avatar()
        # instance.send_email_notification()
        pass
```

This callback will block the `save` method, so you can do things like trigger notifications or update the model further before your response is sent back over the wire, whether you're using forms or the Django REST framework for AJAX calls. Of course, use responsibly and offload heavy tasks to a job queue instead of keeping your users waiting :)

Answer (score 3):

rather use **pk** instead of **id**:

```
if not self.pk:
  do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the common way to do so.

the id will be given while saved first time to the db

Answer (score 1):

```
> def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
>         if form.instance._state.adding:
>             form.instance.author = request.user
>             super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
>         else:
>             obj.updated_by = request.user.username
> 
>             super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Using cleaned_data.get(), I was able to determine whether I had an instance, I also had a CharField where null and blank where true. This will update at each update according to the logged in user

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for all the above scenarios?

```
if self.pk is not None and <ModelName>.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).exists():
...
```

Comment: this would cause an additional database hit.

Answer (score 0):

A more modern approach For Python3.8 and above using the walrus operator. (if you want to save some lines of code)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if is_new_obj := self._state.adding:
        # Do some Pre_Save processing for new objects to be created
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_new_obj:
        # Do some Post_Save processing for newly created objects
```

Answer (score -1):

In python 3 and django 3 this is what's working in my project:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
   if not change:
      #put your code here when adding a new object.
```

Answer (score -3):

To know whether you are updating or inserting the object (data), use `self.instance.fieldname` in your form. Define a clean function in your form and check whether the current value entry is same as the previous, if not then you are updating it.

`self.instance` and `self.instance.fieldname` compare with the new value