# How do you detect a new instance of the model in Django's model.save()

Tags: django, django-models

While overriding the specific model's save() method, Is it possible determine whether it's a new record or an update?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If `self.pk` is `None` it is a new record.

```
def save(self):
    if self.pk is None:
        self.created = datetime.today()
    self.modified = datetime.today()
    super(ProjectCost, self).save()
```

This topic has been discussed also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907695/in-a-django-model-custom-save-method-how-should-you-identify-a-new-object)

Comment: Please let me note here, that Django has built-in keywords for recording the object creation and modification dates: you can use the `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` parameters of `DateTimeField` in the model definition.

Comment: pk is not `None` if you are using UUIDField for pk - even if the instance is new.

Comment: This will NOT work when you are saving a multi-table Child Model Class. The parent instance is created first before saving the child instance. And by default, the pk for the child instance is attained from the parent instance's pk. So, it will never be `None`.

Answer (score 9):

The preferred solution in modern Django is to check `self._state.adding`

This is now documented here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model._state

Comment: I just posted a comment about this in another topic (from 2017), but this one is much more current, so I'll ask here as well.  What's the definitive stance on using "private" properties/methods.  I know Python doesn't actually have private properties, that the "_" is merely an accepted convention.  But I'm curious to know if it's ok to rely on ```_state```.

Comment: @ExTexan the whole underscore private thing is a convention. You could choose to have underscores mean something else, or nothing at all. With regard to Django they have stated that _state and _meta are public API's that you are free to use. They have names starting underscore to prevent them from clashing with user fields. Not because they are private.