# Modifying an image after saving it with ImageField

Tags: django, django-models

I'm completely lost on how I should modify an image after it's saved.  I have a model:

```
class Pic(models.Model):
    imgfile = FaceChopField(upload_to='img/%m/%d')
```

The image is uploaded just fine.  I've looked up this question a bunch, and I've found a number of snippets and similar questions, but I'm still terribly confused.  Yes, I have gone through a bunch of searches regarding this exact sort of confusion/issue.

Is there any way I can just:

1. Access the saved image directory.
2. Locate the image uploaded by name/directory.
3. Run my modify_image(filename) on the image.
4. Save the modified image in some other directory.

I've read through documentation on the Django site on managing files, and I've pored over StackOverflow for a while, trying different solutions.  All I'm asking for is, perhaps, a straightforward approach to the aforementioned.  You don't even need to show me any code if it's too much of a bother.  I'm just at a loss and I don't know what I'm doing at this point, so some algorithmic layout of a solution would be great.  Thank you.

---

**Here's my current attempt:**

```
class FaceChopFieldFile(ImageFieldFile):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FaceChopFieldFile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        super(FaceChopFieldFile, self).save()
        image_content = facechop(self.path) #my image modification function

        self.storage.save(self.path, image_content)


class FaceChopField(ImageField):
    attr_class = FaceChopFieldFile    


class Pic(models.Model): 
    imgfile =  FaceChopField(upload_to='img/%m/%d')
```

Anything wrong?

Comment: Here is an example of resizing an image after saving: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1100/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my own problem.  Turned out I was overriding save() incorrectly:

```
class FaceChopFieldFile(ImageFieldFile):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FaceChopFieldFile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, name, content, save=True):
        super(FaceChopFieldFile, self).save(name, content, save)
        image_content = facechop(self.path) #my image modification function

        self.storage.save(self.path, image_content)


class FaceChopField(ImageField):
    attr_class = FaceChopFieldFile



class Pic(models.Model): 
    imgfile =  FaceChopField(upload_to='img/%m/%d')
```

**The problem was:**

```
def save(self):
    super(FaceChopFieldFile, self).save()
```

**So I changed it to:**

```
def save(self, name, content, save=True):
            super(FaceChopFieldFile, self).save(name, content, save)
```

It does exactly what I want it to do now.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is a **hook** that is called when an object is just about to be saved to DB. What I'd do is have all the image processing logic within function that **overrides [save method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574367/django-overriding-save-method-in-model)** of your model. However this would slowdown the user experience of you site. In that situation what I'd recommend is writing [celery task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html). Even better you can run a [periodic task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: This doesn't help me at all, sorry.