# Creating model instance in another app

Tags: django, django-models

I have a System model in one app that I'd like to connect to a Queue model in another app (django-helpdesk). If no Queue object is selected for a System object, I'd like to initialize a new Queue object, using information from the System to generate it.

I've covered all of the required fields for the Queue, and yet this doesn't seem to work. It doesn't throw an error; it just never generates a new Queue object. Can anyone spot the issue in question, or recommend another way of covering this?

```
#models.py

import helpdesk

....

class System(models.Model):
    queue = models.ForeignKey(
        helpdesk.models.Queue,
        blank = True,
        null = True,
        editable = True,
        verbose_name = _('Queue'),
    )

    def __save__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.queue:
            slug = slugify(self.name)
            queue = helpdesk.models.Queue(title=self.name, slug=slug)
            queue.save()
        self.queue = queue.pk
        super(System, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT: For reference, there's an additional mistake beyond using the double underscores for the `save()` method. The line `self.queue = queue.pk` should instead be `self.queue = queue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `save()` method, not `__save__()`, see examples:

- [Django. Override save for model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269605/django-overwrite-save-for-model)
- [How do you detect a new instance of the model in Django's model.save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574367/django-overriding-save-method-in-model)

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rename:

```
def __save__(...)
```

to

```
def save(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for the double underscores in the `save()` method. That's for Python magic methods only.