# Check if object with OneToOneField is new or already exists

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models

The common pattern for checking if an object is new is testing for:

```
self.pk is not None
```

As described in [In a django model custom save() method, how should you identify a new object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907695/in-a-django-model-custom-save-method-how-should-you-identify-a-new-object)

But it's not true when the oject is in one-to-one relation to some other object, say:

```
class X(models.Model):
     bla = models.OneToOneField(Bla)
```

Then if I want to create this object instance and save it to database I have do this:

```
x = X(bla=someBla)
x.save()
```

And x.pk is not null but x.pk = someBla.pk from the very begining.

So is there any posssibility to check if such an object is new or edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new  =  not bool(X.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).count())
```

Comment: if not self._meta.model.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).count()

Answer (score -1):

`self.pk` in save method will be None in this case, but make sure that you're checking this **before** calling super.save() in the save() method of class X.

Comment: def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        print ("pk=%s") % self.pk

Never shows None, so it's not true.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Why not use ForeignKey with unique=True? [See the differences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5891861/912039). As to why this happens, according to an answer in that thread, OneToOneField represents composition, so it makes sense to assign the primary key of the related object upon instantiation.

Comment: Because I would need to have additional id column somewere. I'm working with lagacy database and I can't just change OneToOne to ForeignKey.

Comment: In that case, the only option is to query the database in the save method to see if the object exists, and act accordingly (X.objects.get(pk=self.pk) and catch DoesNotExist).

Comment: Almost there, but instead of get I'll be using filter.count() to avoid raising exceptions.