# Identifying new Model Instance in Django Save with UUID pk

Tags: django, django-models

If I have a model that has a `UUID` primary key and the the user may set the value on creation, is there any way to tell within the `save` method that the instance is new?

Previous techniques of checking the auto assigned fields: [In a django model custom save() method, how should you identify a new object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907695/in-a-django-model-custom-save-method-how-should-you-identify-a-new-object/940928#940928) do not work.

Answer (score 3):

Use `self._state.adding`. It defaults to `True` and gets set to `False` after saving the model instance or loading it from the DB.

You should also check the `force_insert` argument of `save`.

Note that this will not work if you attempt to copy an instance by changing its `id` and saving (a common shortcut). If you need to detect this, you could override the instance saving and loading to also store the `pk` on `self._state`, then compare the current `pk` with `self._state.pk`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Fixed the phrasing. @Steve

Answer (score 0):

In `save()`, **self.pk is None** with pk (uuid) dont work because it should has `default = uuid.uuid4` and if you set it to `default = None` primarykey should has default attribute as valid uuid in DB, so let `default = uuid.uuid4` in UUID field.

The esay way is to add field `created_at`:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and in `save()` use :

```
if self.created_at is None:
  your code here
```

Answer (score -1):

`save` takes an optional parameter, `force_insert`. Passing that as True will force Django to do an INSERT. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: how to tell if an instance is new or an update.

Answer (score -1):

You can use django-model-utils [TimeStampedModel](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#timestampedmodel) (you can also use django-extensions [TimeStampedModel](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/model_extensions.html?highlight=timestampedmodel) or make your own).

This provides each model a `created` and `modified` field. Then, compare the timedelta between the new instance's `created` and `modified` fields to an arbitrary time difference (this example uses 5 seconds). This allows you to identify if an instance is new:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(<ModelName>, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    if (self.modified - self.created).seconds < 5:
        <the instance is new>
```