# save() method for django_comments_xtd model

Tags: django, wagtail, django-comments

I am using Wagtail + Django_comments_xtd + Django.

##### My_Django_App/models.py

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page
class PostPage(Page):
  ...


from django_comments_xtd.models import XtdComment
class PostComment(XtdComment):
    page = ParentalKey('PostPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rn_comments')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user:
            self.user_name = self.user.username
        self.page = PostDetail.objects.get(pk=self.object_pk)
        super(PostComment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

On Wagtail CMS, if I revise an existing post which has some comments already and publish the revised post again, I thought **`PostComment.save()`** should not be triggered any more. However, during my debug, I found it was triggered unexpectedly.

I guess that I need to fine-tune **`PostComment.save()`** to achieve above intention.

After some researches on StackOverflow,

- **[Identifying new Model Instance in Django Save with UUID pk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127768/identifying-new-model-instance-in-django-save-with-uuid-pk)**
- **[In a django model custom save() method, how should you identify a new object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907695/in-a-django-model-custom-save-method-how-should-you-identify-a-new-object/35647389#35647389)**

I realize that I might need to use **`PostComment._state.adding`** and **`force_insert`** within the **`save()`** to achieve my intention.

Can anyone show me how should I fine-tune **`PostComment.save()`** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out myself. I was using **`ParentalKey`** to link **`PostComment`** model to wagtail page model **`PostPage`**.

```
class PostComment(XtdComment):
    # page = ParentalKey('PostPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rn_comments')
```

Due to how **`modelcluster`** (where `ParentalKey` originates from) works, every time **`PostPage`** is revised and re-published, the **`PostComment.save()`** will be triggerred.

After I change **`ParentalKey`** to **`models.ForeignKey`**, the **`PostComment.save()`** is not triggerred anymore after **`PostPage`** is revised and re-published.

```
class PostComment(XtdComment):
    # page = models.ForeignKey('PostPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rn_comments')
```