# Generating files after adding model instance through django admin interface

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I'm writing a model for a website. When a user adds an instance of the model through the Django admin, I want to catch the event and automatically generate files, including adding a reference path field for those created files.

The model form (used for the admin site) has a [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method that can be overridden. I can create and update files and fields through this.

```
def clean(self):
    info = self.cleaned_data.get('info')

    ... #Generate IO paths from info

    self.cleaned_data['template_path'] = template_path
    self.instance.template_path = template_path

    return self.cleaned_data
```

I need to create a distinction between `add` and `change` events, so I'm not writing files and changing the pathing post object creation. Is there a way to do this within `clean`, or should I be looking elsewhere to create fields & update fields?

Comment: Here's how to differentiate between new and existing objects in a custom save() method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35647389/8893667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning a ModelForm doesn't necessarily mean that the Model instance will get saved.

You can do this in the Model's save() method or [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal so that it is certain.

That being said, to distinguish between add and change, you may first query the database for an instance with same id prior to saving.

```
if instance.pk and instance.__class__.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk):
    # Editing existing instance, skip
    pass
else:
    # New instance. do whatever you want
```

In your case *instance* becomes *self.instance*

Comment: Also you can save that database query by using instance._state. See @Endre Both's comment in the question

Comment: I implemented this through the save method. Much better workflow, but I just had to make sure I was calling super().save() _after_ my conditional check and updating of custom fields. Works well.